# JSON Schema for validation JSON object with an array of items of the same type

Tags: json, jsonschema

Can i create json schema for validitaion this object without redesigning json in other form?

```
{      
        "itemColors": {
          "40": "#12ffd6",
          "69": "#f90861",
          "185": "#063ac3"
        },
        "itemVisible": {
          "32": true,
          "33": true,
          "34": true,
          "36": true,
          "37": true,
          "38": true,
          "39": true,
          "40": true,
          "41": true,
          "55": true,
          "56": true,
          "69": true,
          "185": true,
          "187": true,
          "196": true,
          "197": true,
          "198": true
        } 

}
```

Objects can have different numbers of properties.

Values for ItemColors:

- must be of type string
- do not have to be unique
- can be any number of them

Same thing for itemVisible but values must be of type boolean

Comment: You need to provide more detail. Yes, you can create a schema for this specific JSON document; however, I suspect you don't want that. What is it that you actually want to validate? Is it enough to validate that the values for itemColors should be of type string? That they should be unique? That there should be a maximum of 3 of them? Without this information we cannot help you and your post will probably be closed.

Comment: Post was corrected

Comment: What about itemVisible?

Comment: the same, but with boolean values

Comment: Fixed that for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the schema of unspecified properties using `"additionalProperties"` :

```
{
   "properties" : {
       "itemColors" : {
            "type" : "object",
            "additionalProperties" : {
                "type" : "string"
            }
       },
       "itemsVisible" : {
            "type" : "object",
            "additionalProperties" : {
                "type" : "boolean"
            }
       }
   }
}
```

Read more here: https://spacetelescope.github.io/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what i searched